# How to remove custom ticket fields inherited from a global config in Trac?

Tags: trac

I have a few custom ticket fields defined in a global config inherited by all our Trac environments. Now I'd like to remove a few of them only for a single environment (but without having to un-inherit the global config which sets a lot more than just the custom fields). The perhaps obvious way

```
[ticket-custom]
mycustomfield =
```

did not work. Is there any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no limitation for inheritance in general. So you can't stop a configuration part from propagation, once it's inherited.

You could construct a slightly more fragmented inheritance instead of ditching inheritance to still reach your goal:

**global_trac.ini:**

```
all the basic, common stuff

[ticket-custom]
put reduced, common set of custom fields here
```

**global_trac_with_custom_fields.ini:**

```
[inherit]
file = ../global_trac.ini

[ticket-custom]
put full set of custom fields here
```

**your_special_trac_env/conf/trac.ini:**

```
[inherit]
file = ../global_trac.ini
```

**some_other_trac_env/conf/trac.ini:**

```
[inherit]
file = ../global_trac_with_custom_fields.ini
```

Comment: Well, some options can just be overridden again with empty values but in this special case (and probably in others, e.g. ticket workflows) you can't un-create things that have been created in an inherited config. Not very nice, but this here works good enough. I created just a second `trac-ticket-custom.ini` without inheriting the global one and instead inherit both when I need them.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting improvement. I knew it could be nicer, but not how to format it right-away.